# Hide Android Soft Navigation in TWA (Bubblewrap)

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity, twa, bubblewrap

I've followed this guide (https://developers.google.com/web/android/trusted-web-activity/quick-start) to build a TWA app, but I need to hide the android soft navigation bar (not the URL bar).

[image: "The bar I'm trying to hide"]

I found this (https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation) but can't figure out where to put the onResume() method.

I haven't made anything in Android Studio before and I'm completely new to this. Would really appreciate the help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

What you are referring to is called [Immersive Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive) on Android.
Starting from version 1.4.0, Bubblewrap CLI evaluates the `display` property of the manifest when initialising an application. If the value is `fullscreen`, it automatically applies the Immersive Mode to your TWA. Make sure to set `display` to `fullscreen` in your web manifest.

For existing apps, update the file `twa-manifest.json` and add/update the `display` attribute to `fullscreen`, then run `bubblewrap update` and `bubblewrap build`.

**Alternate / manual approach:**

It's also possible to manually update the project created by Bubblewrap to use fullscreen / immersive mode:

1. Edit `app/build.gradle` to use the latest version of android-browser-helper version. The `dependencies` section at the bottom of the file should look like the following:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.google.androidbrowserhelper:androidbrowserhelper:1.3.0'
}
```

Notice the minumum version for androidbrowserhelper should be `1.3.0`.

2. Edit `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` and add a new `meta-data` tag with the `android:name` attribute set to `android.support.customtabs.trusted.DISPLAY_MODE` and the `android:value` attribute set to `immersive` to use immersive mode inside the `activity` tag:

```xml
<activity android:name="com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.LauncherActivity"
    android:label="@string/launcherName">

    ...

    <meta-data android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.FALLBACK_STRATEGY"
        android:value="@string/fallbackType" />

    <meta-data android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.DISPLAY_MODE"
    android:value="immersive"/>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    ...
</activity>
```

Now, when running `bubblewrap build`, the application will use the extra meta-tag and launch in fullscreen / immersive mode.

Comment: Thank you!! This was just what I needed